# Box2DWeb - GetBody() not working

Tags: javascript, box2d, box2dweb

I need to get the body of a fixture but when I call the fixture.GetBody() function, It returns this error: Object # has no method 'GetBody';

here is the code:

var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;

```
var bouncebodyDef = new b2BodyDef;

bouncebodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;   

var bounceDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    bounceDef.density = 1;
    bounceDef.body = bouncebodyDef;
    bounceDef.friction = 1;
    bounceDef.restitution = 0;
    bounceDef.userData = 'bounce';

bounceDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
bounceDef.shape.SetAsBox(1.5, 0.1);
bouncebodyDef.position.Set(2, 12);
bouncebodyDef.angle = (3.4);
world.CreateBody(bouncebodyDef).CreateFixture(bounceDef);

console.log(bounceDef.GetBody());
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b2FixtureDef` doesn't have a getBody(), so that's what the error means.  The documentation for [b2FixtureDef](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/) is linked there.  It doesn't look like the Fixture type even has a body that you can set, like in the line `bounceDef.body = bouncebodyDef;`